# Pythonic way to describe "magic objects" (in the sense of "magic numbers")

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have objects of class `Node`, they get compared by an id. Now I also have nodes with a special meaning, `SpecialNodeA` and `SpecialNodeB`. They do not have any properties, they just transport their special meaning by being that type/that object. It would call them "magic objects" since they have a similiar function as "magic numbers".

As was said in a comment below: I'm looking for something like a singleton that is only equal to itself. It will be compared to other types and should not throw an Exception, just give false.

I currently do it the following way:

```
class Node:
  def __eq_(self, other)
    return (self.id == other.id)

class SpecialNodeA:
  pass;

class SpecialNodeB:
  pass;

spNoA = SpecialNodeA() # 
spNoB = SpecialNodeB()

n1 = Node(id = 1)
specialNodeA1 = spNoA
specialNodeA2 = spNoA
specialNodeB1 = spNoB
specialNodeB2 = spNoB

print(n1 == specialNode1) # should return false
print(specialNodeA1 == specialNodeA2) # should return true
print(specialNodeA1 == specialNodeB2) # should return false
```

**It works fine, but is there a "more pythonic" way to implement such "magic objects"?**

Comment: It's unclear what you asking for. It smells like you want to `SpecialNodeA` and `SpecialNodeB` be singletons equal only to themselves, and multiple `Node` instances (with different ids), but I'm not really sure. May it be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: I added this in the question, but I think it should be pretty clear considering the code example.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use an [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html):

```
from enum import Enum
class SpecialNodes(Enum):
    A = 1
    B = 2
```

Or if you want actual nodes:

```
class SpecialNodes(Enum):
    A = Node()
    B = Node()
```

Sample:

```
>>> class Node:
...     pass
... 
>>> class SpecialNodes(Enum):
...     B=Node()
...     A=Node()
... 
>>> A1 = SpecialNodes.A
>>> A2 = SpecialNodes.A
>>> B1 = SpecialNodes.B
>>> A1 == A2
True
>>> A1 == B1
False
```